# Implementing a type map with polymorphic retrieval

Tags: c++

I'm working on an event system that allows triggers to send events to either a single handler or all handlers associated with a given type. The former is basic map functionality, and the latter mostly fits the bill... unless you want polymorphic behavior.

```
class Parent {};
class Child : public Parent {};    

// ...

Parent p; Child c;
Trigger trigger;
Handler h1(&p), h2(&c);

trigger.sendToType<Child>(Event());  // sends the event to h2; OK
trigger.sendToType<Parent>(Event()); // sends the event to h1 only; NO
```

Handlers are registered based on the type of pointer they're created with. The "type" of `h1` is `Parent` and the "type" of `h2` is `Child`. With the basic type id mapping used in the dispatcher (just some type-associated integer mapped to a vector of `Handler*`) there's no way to send events to children when sending to parents.

The only solutions I can think of have several downsides:

- O(n) search for sending to a type.
- Having to add reflection to the codebase
- High amounts of manual setup

Ideally, I'd like a solution where overhead is reduced to (number of children + 1 for the actual type) lookups per send to type, but that may not be possible. Any advice?

Comment: It always bugs me when people who don't know how to do something make all sorts of assumptions about how things must be done in their question.  "trivially" "naturally" "Unfortunately"  It sounds like you have your mind made up already.  You've spent all this time trying to tell us what you've though of and not enough talking about what you're really trying to solve.  You've already cornered yourself into a solution for a problem no one else knows.  This post, as is, is a better fit for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: how about using dynamic_cast ?

Comment: @xaxxon sorry if I came across as condescending or unreceptive, that wasn't my intention. The reason I provided so much information was because I thought it might clarify what I'm looking for. I'll remove the fluff if that makes it a better question.

Comment: @budjmt what will make it better is a better description of the problem you're trying to solve with this approach.   Mixing runtime and compile time is a strong sign you haven't thought through your problem and doesn't have clean solutions -- but the problem you're really trying to solve probably has a much better, already solved approach.

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest possible solution is to use dynamic_cast. May be it is not optimal in terms of performance, but should be faster than map/hash

[Here is implementation - test online](http://cpp.sh/4mzl2)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Event
{
    std::string what;
};

class Parent
{
public:
    virtual void process(const Event& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what << "Parent" << std::endl;
    }
};
class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    virtual void process(const Event& e) override
    {
        std::cout << e.what << "Child" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
void handler(Parent* obj, const Event& e)
{
    if (T* tmp = dynamic_cast<T*>(obj))
        tmp->process(e);
}

template<typename T, typename PARENT>
std::vector<T*> select_objects(const std::vector<PARENT*>& objects)
{
    std::vector<T*> res;
    for (auto obj : objects)
    {
        if (T* tmp = dynamic_cast<T*>(obj))
            res.push_back(tmp);
    }
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Parent*> objects = {new Parent, new Child};

    Event e{"Hello from "};
    std::cout << "All objects" << std::endl;    
    for (auto p : objects)
        handler<Parent>(p, e);
    std::cout << "Child objects only" << std::endl;    
    for (auto p : objects)
        handler<Child>(p, e);

    // here we can build an index to access objects faster
    std::cout << "Child objects only using select" << std::endl;    
    std::vector<Child*> children = select_objects<Child>(objects);
    for (auto o : children)
        o->process(e);
}
```

Output:

```
All objects
Hello from Parent
Hello from Child
Child objects only
Hello from Child
Child objects only using select
Hello from Child
```

**UPDATE:** you can build some index to access objects faster

Comment: This looks like a pretty good solution! I think I could adapt this to make it work. It has the issue of O(n) send to type, but that may or may not be unavoidable. Let me make a few edits to the question.

Comment: This only allows one implementation of a handler per type.

Comment: @budjmt " issue of O(n) send to type,"  It's bad form to create new requirements in response to answers.

Comment: @xaxxon You're absolutely right; I meant to imply that requirement with the list of "solutions." The edits simplify what I'm asking about significantly.

Comment: @budjmt , you can build an index and solve the O(n) issue

Comment: the "o(n)" issue may not be an issue.   Often times "slower" algorithms are actually quite a bit faster given the data sets actually in play.  So many people complain about an O(n) algorithm when they're going to put 10 things in it.  They build up some sort of linked tree structure full of cache misses and main memory loads to hold their 10 elements.